# Angular 8: Unit Test Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ApplicationModule: (?)

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I am attempting to run a Jasmine test on an Angular service that uses http:

```js
import { PostService } from './post.service';
import { Post } from '../_model/post';
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

describe('PostService', () => {

  let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;
  let service: PostService;
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.resetTestEnvironment();
    TestBed.initTestEnvironment(BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
      platformBrowserDynamicTesting());

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [PostService],
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule]
    });

    httpTestingController = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
    service = TestBed.get(PostService);

    // setting up mock localStorage
    let store = {};
    const mockLocalStorage = {
      getItem: (key: string): string => {
        return key in store ? store[key] : null;
      },
      setItem: (key: string, value: string) => {
        store[key] = `${value}`;
      },
      removeItem: (key: string) => {
        delete store[key];
      },
      clear: () => {
        store = {};
      }
    };

    spyOn(localStorage, 'getItem')
      .and.callFake(mockLocalStorage.getItem);
    spyOn(localStorage, 'setItem')
      .and.callFake(mockLocalStorage.setItem);
    spyOn(localStorage, 'removeItem')
      .and.callFake(mockLocalStorage.removeItem);
    spyOn(localStorage, 'clear')
      .and.callFake(mockLocalStorage.clear);

  });

  afterEach(() => {
    httpTestingController.verify();
  });


  describe('getAll', () => {
    it('should return an observable of Posts', () => {

      const postData: Post[] = [
        {id: '6aba8f8f-cd43-4b1c-b3a4-21aba97ab620', title: 'CSS Layouts: Justified Elements', created: '2018-3-20', content: 'css-layouts-justified-elements'},
        {id: 'c49439a4-a24a-4e1b-bc92-ebad6caf5e74', title: 'The 4 Constraints of Project Management', created: '2018-02-05', content: 'the-4-constraints-of-project-management'},
        {id: '23723e52-9f0d-4a5d-94e6-196382456258', title: 'Want a Project to Succeed? Gather Good Estimates', created: '2018-1-26', content: 'want-a-project-to-succeed-gather-good-estimates'},
        {id: '69870c97-6736-4956-9826-8af4b2216a79', title: 'Measuring Technical Debt', created: '2019-7-7', content: 'measuring-technical-debt'},
        {id: 'd05ee0b1-ade2-406c-a9ae-d22ba0229341', title: 'Estimations: Coping with Uncertainty', created: '2018-02-08', content: 'estimations-coping-with-uncertainty'}
      ];

      service.getAll().subscribe(posts => {
        expect(posts.length).toEqual(5);
      });

      const req = httpTestingController.expectOne('http://localhost:8089/posts');

      expect(req.request.method).toEqual('GET');

      req.flush(postData); // get the Observable to resolve 'flush' with the PostData
    });

    it('should be created', () => {
      expect(service).toBeTruthy();
    });

  });

});
```

Much of the test isn't there yet, I'm just trying to get things working.

Basically, the test fails near to launch with the error:

```
Failed: Can't resolve all parameters for ApplicationModule: (?).
Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ApplicationModule: (?).
    at syntaxError (/Users/mikecoxon/dev/ws-other/packages/compiler/src/util.ts:100:17)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (/Users/mikecoxon/dev/ws-other/packages/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.ts:957:27)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (/Users/mikecoxon/dev/ws-other/packages/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.ts:836:20)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (/Users/mikecoxon/dev/ws-other/packages/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.ts:680:18)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleSummary (/Users/mikecoxon/dev/ws-other/packages/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.ts:450:31)
    at /Users/mikecoxon/dev/ws-other/packages/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.ts:586:44
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (/Users/mikecoxon/dev/ws-other/packages/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.ts:569:43)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleSummary (/Users/mikecoxon/dev/ws-other/packages/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.ts:450:31)
    at /Users/mikecoxon/dev/ws-other/packages/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.ts:586:44
From: Task: Run beforeEach in control flow
    at UserContext.<anonymous> (/Users/mikecoxon/dev/ws-other/blog/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:94:19)
    at attempt (/Users/mikecoxon/dev/ws-other/blog/node_modules/jasmine/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:4297:26)
    at QueueRunner.run (/Users/mikecoxon/dev/ws-other/blog/node_modules/jasmine/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:4217:20)
    at runNext (/Users/mikecoxon/dev/ws-other/blog/node_modules/jasmine/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:4257:20)
    at /Users/mikecoxon/dev/ws-other/blog/node_modules/jasmine/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:4264:13
    at /Users/mikecoxon/dev/ws-other/blog/node_modules/jasmine/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:4172:9
    at /Users/mikecoxon/dev/ws-other/blog/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:64:48
    at ControlFlow.emit (/Users/mikecoxon/dev/ws-other/blog/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/events.js:62:21)
    at ControlFlow.shutdown_ (/Users/mikecoxon/dev/ws-other/blog/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2674:10)
    at shutdownTask_.MicroTask (/Users/mikecoxon/dev/ws-other/blog/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2599:53)
From asynchronous test: 
Error: 
    at Suite.<anonymous> (/Users/mikecoxon/dev/ws-other/blog/src/app/_services/post.service.spec.ts:20:3)
    at addSpecsToSuite (/Users/mikecoxon/dev/ws-other/blog/node_modules/jasmine/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1107:25)
    at Env.describe (/Users/mikecoxon/dev/ws-other/blog/node_modules/jasmine/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1074:7)
    at describe (/Users/mikecoxon/dev/ws-other/blog/node_modules/jasmine/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:4399:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mikecoxon/dev/ws-other/blog/src/app/_services/post.service.spec.ts:16:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Module.m._compile (/Users/mikecoxon/dev/ws-other/blog/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:473:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (/Users/mikecoxon/dev/ws-other/blog/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:476:12)
```

The tested service itself is a pretty stock-standard http service with nothing fancy in it. I'm fairly sure the problem isn't in there, rather it looks like my package dependencies (I think). I'm not sure how I ended up with a very new version of typescript, but I had to run the following commands to get everything to compile again:

```sh
$ npm i -g npm-check-updates
$ npm install -g npm
$ npm install
```

And finally downgrade typescript from 3.5.4 with:

```sh
$ npm i typescript@3.4.5 --save-dev --save-exact
```

and now `package.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "blog",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "~8.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~8.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~8.1.1",
    "ngx-markdown": "^8.1.0",
    "ngx-markdown-editor": "^1.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.2",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.801.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.1.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.1.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.13",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.6",
    "@types/node": "~12.6.2",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.0.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.5",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.2",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.18.0",
    "typescript": "3.5.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.9.1"
  }
}
```

I put the tested service and app.component.ts in codepens fro reference:[app.component.ts](https://codepen.io/mikecoxon/pen/jjoyPm), [post.service.ts](https://codepen.io/mikecoxon/pen/wLbgMz).

So does anyone know why this is happening? In fact what does `Failed: Can't resolve all parameters for ApplicationModule: (?).` mean exactly?

**UPDATE:**

I have completely rebuilt the project from scratch using Angular 8.1 cli, and the issue remains. It seems clear to me that the problem is coming out of the test somewhere, because the rest of the project works as in the routing, the services, the components etc.I'm going to start stripping down the test to see where it breaks.

**UPDATE 2:**
OK, so even on the following minimal test, it breaks with the same error:

```js
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { PostContentService } from './post.content.service';
import {BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';
import {AppComponent} from '../app.component';

describe('PostContentService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {

    TestBed.resetTestEnvironment();
    TestBed.initTestEnvironment(BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
      platformBrowserDynamicTesting());

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ AppComponent ],
    });

  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    const service: PostContentService = TestBed.get(PostContentService);
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

So I'm thinking now that there's some basic issue with Angular 8 and jasmine testing, perhaps there's a circular dependency somewhere, or some other reason that we get this rather inscrutable error. I'd be very interested to know if others are getting this error. My next move is to try all of this with Jest, and see if I get any further.

Comment: Hi! (Assuming your running `ng test`) did you try downgrading ng to specifically to 8.0.0?

Comment: I first encountered the error on 8.0.0, I upgraded to try to get past it, but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm facing the same issue..

Comment: No, I'm afraid not, I abandoned it for a while and went onto other things. I would love to get an answer to this.

Answer (score -1):

You need to import/inject the Postservice dependencies as well, assuming it’s a http-client you need to have:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
```

and other dependencies related to the http api

**UPDATE:**

As mentioned before you need to import above aswell as you need to import or mock the  rest of the dependencies in your PostService such as:

```
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment.prod';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Post } from '../_model/post';
import { ApiResponse } from '../_model/api.response';
import { ResponseHandler } from '../_helpers/response.handler';
```

Comment: HttpClient is already being `import`ed in the tested class `post.service.ts` - I tried adding this to the spec and, apart from the linter complaining that it was unnecessary, it made no difference and the error remains. Perhaps I've misunderstood where these imports are to go?

Comment: Things has moved around on the latest releases but you used to have to inject it into the actual test. Will try to replicate your issue on a stackblitz. Don’t have a computer available just now ^^